# iphone mkmapview hides/remove nagivationbar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, mkmapview, uinavigationbar

i'm developing a navigation based iphone application that at certain point shows a MKMapView with one annotaions(the view that show the map is inside a tabbar). The problem is when i start zooming or moving  on the map, the navigation bar (under a navigation controller set in appdelegate) gets completely hide or remove and the map gets all way up on the screen! This thing happen only on the device and not in the simulator

thanks

claudio

Comment: How are you displaying the MKMapView? Are you using a UINavigationController with a UIViewController as the root view controller containing the MKMapView?

Answer (score 0):

this is how the app is created:

```
-UINavigationController
--UIViewController
---UITabBar
----UIViewController (Tab1)
----UIViewController (Tab2)
-----MKMapView
```

hope this kind of explanation helps.
thanks
claudio